# JS Array Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this array:

```
var Test1 = [
 {ex: 'ABC', exx: 1},
 {ex: 'BCA', exx: 2},
 {ex: 'CBA', exx: 2}
];
```

And I'm developing a bar graph using the Canvas element, and I would like to know if I could go fetch the values from my array to be displayed and, how to do it.

Comment: any image which you want to draw, and what you tried share ?

Comment: can u add the code related to ur `bar graph`?

Comment: @Salman https://jsfiddle.net/nk6fbzba/

Comment: I would like to know how to fetch the data from my array to display where it is ' Ex ' and ' Exx '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem, u can access the elements from `Test1` very easily:

```
console.log("ex: "+Test1[0].ex+"   exx: "+Test1[0].exx);
```

or in a loop

```
for(var i=0;i< Test1.length;i++)
console.log("ex: "+Test1[i].ex+"   exx: "+Test1[i].exx);
```

A DOM is nothing more than your html page. When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a **Document Object Model** of the page. Meanwhile the `Test1` is your object in **js** script. So, unfortunately, **No**. Your DOM is nothing more than a set of html tags such as `head`, `body`,etc. Of course, **it is able to render the values of scripts into the page**, but *it cannot fetch them on its own*.

This should gives you some part of ur solution

```js
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    
    //horizontal axe
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 630);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 630);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //Vertical axe
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 630);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 430);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //30 in vertical
    
    ctx.font = 'bold small-caps sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'BLACK';
    ctx.fillText('30.000', 2, 485);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 480);
    ctx.lineTo(40, 480);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //20 in vertical
    ctx.fillText('20.000', 2, 535);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 530);
    ctx.lineTo(40, 530);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    
    //10 in vertical
    
    ctx.font = 'bold small-caps sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'BLACK';
    ctx.fillText('10.000', 2, 585);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 580);
    ctx.lineTo(40, 580);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    
    var Test1 = [
     {ex: 'ABC', exx: 1},
     {ex: 'BCA', exx: 2},
     {ex: 'CBA', exx: 2}
    ];
    ///*
    for(var i=0;i< Test1.length;i++){
         // console.log("ex: "+Test1[i].ex+"   exx: "+Test1[i].exx);   
      ctx.font = 'bold small-caps sans-serif';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'BLACK';
        ctx.fillText(Test1[i].ex,100+ i*135, 660);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(i*100, 630);
        ctx.lineTo(i*100, 640);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(100+i*100, 400, 100, Test1[i].exx*100);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#5b5b5b';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
        
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="700"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes I know, and thanks for your reply but is there any way to do it using DOM?

Comment: @PedroCarvalho i hope, it helps u to get some part of ur solution. I have no time to complete it more. Please upvote me if it helps u.